# Why ASP.NET Core application not loading in iframe in the same domain?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iframe

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC website that is the src of an IFRAME inside a portal. Both the portal an the .NETCore application have the same domain (eg. site.portal.domain / portal.domain).

When I enter the portal, I get a message in the browsers:

> mysite.portal.domain refused to connect

(on Chrome), the other browser give different errors, like IE 11 gives:

> This content cannot be displayed in a frame

On Chrome debug I found the message:

> Refused to display 'https://site.portal.domain' in a frame because it
>   set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Any hints on how to solve that?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`X-FRAME-OPTIONS` is used to protect against [clickjacking](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking) attempts. If you own the application and want it be framed , you can skip the restrict ：

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```

By default, the X-Frame-Options header is generated with the value SAMEORIGIN. If this setting is 'true', the X-Frame-Options header will not be generated for the response.

Comment: That helped me fixing it, but your code didn't work. Please edit your answer with the line that worked: I added `services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);` to ConfigureServices in Startup.

Comment: that solved the problem for Chrome and IE 11, but when I try IE 9 I still get the same error. Do you have any ideia what is could be?

Comment: For IE9 you have to explicitly add the header with allow. A simple, but insecure fix for this version compatibility is adding ```app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "AllowAll");
                await next();
            });``` Or, better of adding the URL you allow.